# Unit-Testing an Action with NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks, restsharp

I'd like to unit-test the following function with NUnit and Rhino Mocks. The function uses the given parameters to create a `RestSharp.RestRequest` and give the request to the `dataAccessApi`:

```
public void CopyToUserSession(string uri, string sourcePath)
{
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(uri, Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("source-path", sourcePath);

    dataAccessApi.Request<object>(request, restExecution.Get);
}
```

This is the testing Class:

```
public void CopyToUserSession_ValidUriAndParameter_CallDataAccessRequest()
{
    // Arrange
    var dataAccessApi = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDataAccessApi>();
    var restExecution = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRestExecution>();
    var sinkNodeResource = new SinkNodeResource(dataAccessApi, restExecution);

    string uri = "http://SomeUri.com";
    string sourcePath = "Some Source Path";

    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(uri, Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("source-path", sourcePath);

    // Act
    sinkNodeResource.CopyToUserSession(uri, sourcePath);

    // Assert
    dataAccessApi.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Request<object>(request, restExecution.Get));
}
```

The IDataAccessApi...:

```
public interface IDataAccessApi
{
    void Request<T>(RestRequest request, Action<T> callbackAction) where T : new();
}
```

... and the IRestExecution:

```
public interface IRestExecution
{
    void Get(object o);

    void Put(object o);

    void Post(object o);

    void Delete(object o);
}
```

The test worked with easier functions to call (like `x.Test("Some String")`) but does not with the Action `new RestExecution().Get` - how do i unit-test such calls?

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Edit:** Changed the Code regarding @rich.okelly comment.

**Edit:** Added the code for the interfaces

Comment: The `RestExecution.Get` method group passed in the assertion is different (not reference equal) to the one called in your code.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the code, implementing another Interface for `restExecution `, hoping the methods would be reference equal - bit it still won't pass the test.

Comment: How is the `IDataAccessApi` interface defined and more specifically what's the signature of the `Request<T>` method?

Comment: I added the source for the `IDataAccessApi` and the `IRestExecution`-Interface. Another point i found: could it be that the `request` also is not reference equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
// arrange
var dataAccessApi = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDataAccessApi>();
var restExecution = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRestExecution>();
var sinkNodeResource = new SinkNodeResource(dataAccessApi, restExecution);
string uri = "http://SomeUri.com";
string sourcePath = "Some Source Path";

// act
sinkNodeResource.CopyToUserSession(uri, sourcePath);

// assert
dataAccessApi.AssertWasCalled(
    x => x.Request<object>(
        Arg<RestRequest>.Matches(
            y => y.Method == Method.POST && 
                 y.Resource == uri &&
                 y.Parameters.Count == 1 &&
                 y.Parameters[0].Value as string == sourcePath
        ),
        Arg<Action<object>>.Is.Equal((Action<object>)restExecution.Get)
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you! The code works fine and the method passes the test!